# Add custom attribute to testng-results.xml method tags

Tags: testng, xml-attribute

I get a testng-results.xml file in my test-output directory for my appium project. Inside i get my test results, for example:

```
    <test-method status="PASS" signature="setBeforeEachTest()[pri:0, instance:appium.salesforce1.ios.tests.MyTests]" name="setBeforeEachTest" is-config="true" duration-ms="0" started-at="2016-02-10T14:26:59Z" finished-at="2016-02-10T14:26:59Z">
      <reporter-output>
      </reporter-output>
    </test-method>
```

I want my test-method tag output to be like this:

```
    <test-method build="testBuild" status="PASS" signature="setBeforeEachTest()[pri:0, instance:appium.salesforce1.ios.tests.MyTests]" name="setBeforeEachTest" is-config="true" duration-ms="0" started-at="2016-02-10T14:26:59Z" finished-at="2016-02-10T14:26:59Z">
      <reporter-output>
      </reporter-output>
    </test-method>
```

basically, i want to add another value to the test-method tag. I have tried doing this inside my @Test

```
ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
result.setAttribute("build", "testBuild");
```

but this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Even I need the same functionality in TestNG. @Rafthecalf did you find any way to achieve this

Comment: @SureshKumar, After adding the variable result in the test and set an attribute, make sure you change your pom.xml in order to have the <value>generateTestResultAttributes=true</value>. See the entire setup here: [link](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+TestNG+in+Java) and search for "generateTestResultAttributes" , it will give you the precise location where to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of [`XmlReporter`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/c45ba39b1c7b5aa7b5abd9ef33840497af80bcea/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/XMLReporter.java) does not support custom attributes.

You'll have to contribute a change to add support for custom attributes or create your own reporter. You could copy the existing one and tweak it for your needs.